# SYMFONY 3 -> Could not load type "Tableless\ModelBundle\Form\DatetimeType"

Tags: php, symfony3

Estou aprender SYMFONY 3.
Últimos passos que efetuei antes do erro.:
     criar o crud com o Doctrine ORM
     criar a sua route
     Entrar na pagina post

Após de carregar "Create a new entry" dá o seguinte erro.:
   Could not load type "Tableless\ModelBundle\Form\DatetimeType"
   500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Página "Tableless\ModelBundle\Form\PostType.php"

```
namespace Tableless\ModelBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
   /**
    * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param array $options
    */
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           ->add('title')
           ->add('content')
           ->add('createdAt', 'datetime')
           ->add('updateAt', 'datetime')
       ;
   }

   /**
    * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
    */
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'Tableless\ModelBundle\Entity\Post'
       ));
   }
}
```

O que foi feito incorretamente?
Como posso ultrapassar o constrangimento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário importar.:
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
Alterar

```
->add('createdAt', 'datetime')
->add('updateAt', 'datetime')
```

para

```
->add('createdAt', DateType::class)
->add('updateAt', DateType::class)
```

fonte.:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17510

Ficou assim.:

```
namespace Tableless\ModelBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
   /**
    * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param array $options
    */
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $builder
           ->add('title')
           ->add('content')
           ->add('createdAt', DateType::class)
           ->add('updateAt', DateType::class)
       ;
   }

   /**
    * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
    */
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'Tableless\ModelBundle\Entity\Post'
       ));
   }
}
```